# How can i check session or cookie expiration time in Magento

Tags: magento

I am face a very critical problem with session expiration time. I have set the time 
Cookie lifetime : **Admin panel > system > configuration > Web > Cookie Lifetime = 86400**
Session lifetime :  **Admin panel > system > configuration > Admin > Session Lifetime (seconds) = 86400**

But still users automatically loged out from there accounts after 30 mins.

Is there any way to check session and cookie expiration time?
or i am doing anything wrong to set expiration time.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it as a PHP parameter in your `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400
```

Comment: I have added this but still i am getting the same error

Comment: Can you verify Cookie Lifetime = 86400 is set for ALL scopes in the magento config?